# Multiplying sub-arrays itens in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Ok, i want multiply the numbers inside a sub-array that i've created using: `each_slice(2)`

so far i got:

```
inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
inputArray.each_slice(2).to_a  #[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

whats i've already tried:

```
if inputArray.length % 2 == 0
   newArr = inputArray.each_slice(2).to_a
   newArr = newArr.max #using .max works, but it doesn't always return the rigth value
   newArr.inject(:*)
```

i'm trying to achieve this result:

```
#[[2],[12],[30]]
```

As a novice to Ruby and programming in general i'm out of ideas

Comment: Ruby's naming conventions are such that variable and method names *should not* contain upper-case letters. Use `input_array` here instead of what you have for consistency's sake. Capital letters in Ruby have significant meaning, as a leading capital letter is a constant reserved for `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME` type situations.

Comment: What's up with that `max` thing? Does that have anything to do with your question? How can that *ever* "work" and "return the rigth value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it, but you need to combine things the right way:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

list.each_slice(2).map { |l| [ l.inject(:*) ] }
# => [[2], [12], [30]]
```

The `inject` operation needs to be moved inside the `map` because you're not transforming just one of the items, but each of them in turn.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using inject here @tadman? I jotted down that exact method but decided it would be simpler and more idiomatic to times the values as in my answer.

Comment: When you get used to reducing an array using `inject` like that, it just becomes second nature. In this particular case, where you're dealing with slices of 2, I think the `[x * y]` is actually cleaner

Comment: @Brennan I like using `inject` or `reduce` even in trivial cases because it automatically scales. If you change that `2` to a `3` it works, no other modifications necessary.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Cheers @tadman, makes perfect sense. I guess it's a little bit of accessibility vs flexibility.

Comment: @SRack I try to follow the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) whenever possible. This function takes  arguments where  ≥ 2.

Comment: Isn't it  ≥ 1?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yeah, technically, but `inject` is only necessary with more than one entry per, so, kind of a subjective call.

Comment: Definitely agree with leaning towards inject even in trivial cases, there just are cases where you know you will be handling only 2-tuples, where explicit math may be more relevant to the system you are trying to model

Answer (score 3):

You're along the right lines with `each_slice`. This should do it for you:

```
input_array.each_slice(2).map { |x, y| [x * y] }
=> [[2], [12], [30]]
```

You don't need the `to_a` in there, though it works with a nested array if need be.

This iterates through each sub-array (or slice) and return an array of whatever the block evaluates to for each pair. For example, here it multiplies the two elements together and wraps them in a one-item sub-array.

Hope that helps - let me know if you have any questions!